# Click Orders and I'm getting "Information Changes have been made.."

Tags: magento2

I have done a default installation of Magento 2.2.5 CE and when I click on an order in the Magento Admin I get the following error:

**"Order View.  Information changes have been made to this section that have not been saved.  This tab contains invalid data.  Please resolve this before saving"**.

The problem is that I haven't done any messing with the back end code and its a default install.    Where am I going wrong?  There doesn't seem to be any other error messages. (I haven't turned on developer mode).  When I go into the Module Manger there are no modules listed so I don't think its that.  I don't have any extension installed.

I'm baffled. Any help greatly appreciated.

Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabling module Temando_Shipping fixed that

Answer (score 0):

Check the PHP Log.
you'll  must find an error log.
try to resolve the log error first. Also you can check your installed module, It might chances they're conflicting.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).