# Magento 2 & Temando: "Information Changes have been made to this section that have not been saved. This tab contains invalid data."

Tags: magento, magento2

We have the same issue that other users (see below) have had with orders, when we click into a given order we get the error:

"Information Changes have been made to this section that have not been saved. This tab contains invalid data. Please resolve this before saving."

The solutions out there tend to be to disable the Temando module, but we have already done that and we still get the error.

Does anyone know a solution?

This is with CE version 2.2.9

Thanks in advance

Darren

Reference : [Click Orders and I'm getting "Information Changes have been made.."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51381289/click-orders-and-im-getting-information-changes-have-been-made?newreg=b8a362f696d843e489a640874fdc40c8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to disable Temando Shipping module

Comment: It's already uninstalled - that is what everyone has advised to other people but we had already done that